# Why doesn't Google Chrome block all pop-ups?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

For example, if you go to the website nba-stream.com and click on a game, the website will open up a pop-up, but since I have disabled pop-ups in Google Chrome in Chrome://settings, I shouldn't get any pop-ups.
[image: clicking on a game stream on nba-stream.com also opens up a pop-up ad]

but if you visit the same website in Internet Explorer, the browser will block all pop-ups whatsoever:
[image: Internet Explorer 11 blocking pop-up]

Answer (score 1):

clear your cookies --it should block in chrome short of 2 reasons:

1) have previously allowed cookies / pop-ups from that site OR it's domain (knowingly or otherwise)

2) it is using some other trigger like a rogue js script which is not blocked.

Comment: Unfortunately, even after installing the javascript popup blockers in chrome, I still get those popups on nba-stream.com

Comment: Fully clear cache  aka on linux   '  rm -rf ~/.config/google\* '   on windows  remove  ' C:\Users\$USERNAME\Programs/ Files\AppData\Roaming\Google\*

Comment: I don't have a folder called "Google" under C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming

Comment: anything related to google or chrome?

Comment: is it in this directory: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Comment: Should have been in Roaming but yes that one delete It entirely and Close chrome ( confirm no background processes are running) then retry ( so to clarify  Delete EVERYTHING from \Google\......  Directory NOT just UserData

Answer (score 0):

By default google chrome should block all popups. In some cases popups can occur because of extensions (adware) or a form of DNS hijacking. Try checking out this https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!category-topic/chrome/eBasgnkdWds